# How to install and configure shibboleth SP in windows 7

Tags: windows, shibboleth

I want to integrate wordpress with shibboleth SP, for that I need to install and configure Shibboleth SP. I'm working on windows 7.
Please help me for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of the question relating to the installation, I suggest to follow the relevant sections of the documentation:

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPWindowsInstall

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPWindowsIIS7Installer

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPGettingStarted

In a nutshell:

1. Download and run the installer.
   If it succeeds, you should see a Shibboleth 2 Daemon running as a service.
2. Create the ISAPI pointing to isapi_shib.dll (Assuming you are installing 2.5 or later : lib64\shibboleth\isapi_shib.dll in the installation folder)
3. Map the *.sso file extension to the ISAPI library (same dll as at step 2)

At this point you should be able navigate to https://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Status from the actual web server machine (you get a bunch of XML as the result)

Then you have to configure... I do not know the specifics for working with wordpress, and this is too general a question.

One thing which drove me nuts is that some parts of the main configuration file (shibboleth2.xml) have no effect unless IIS is fully restarted. Simply restarting the web site is not enough (even if you did all the setup above at website level)